# printer installation

Tags: brother

I have a brother mfcj6510dw multifunction printer which I am trying to get working with ubuntu 14.04. I would like to know wether anyone else has, or has had the same problem and if they Managed to get theirs working. I have found the Instructions on the brother site to not work. and the Terminal program instructs me to use apt instead.

Comment: This may help
http://askubuntu.com/questions/227318/installling-a-brother-printer-in-ubuntu-12-04-mfcj6510dw

Comment: This is what always worked for our Brother printers: http://askubuntu.com/questions/636363/how-do-i-install-proprietary-drivers-for-my-brother-all-in-one-printer-scanner-f/636364#636364

Comment: After further investigation have found that printer seems to be recognised as a large storage drive. now off to try the solutions suggested by...-Mrinmoy dey and Takkat.

Comment: since posting this question I have managed to set up the printer using a USB connection, and also set-up a network printer using wi-fi. Anyone else having a problem setting up a brother printer should visit the following site:- (https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/15)